# Netbeans Cordova Plugin - The file already exists

Tags: cordova, debian, netbeans-plugins

when attempting to create a new Cordova Application in Netbeans:

File->New Project->Html5->Cordova Aplication

I am unable to move to the NEXT step because of the following error:

```
The file /path/to/the/folder already exists
```

No matter which folder i select or which name i give to the project.

- OS: Debian Wheezy (7.4)
- Netbeans 8.0
- GIT: 1.7.10.4
- Node.js: v0.10.28
- Cordova: 3.5.0-0.2.4

May it be a permissions problem?
Any help is welcome, thank you.

### EDIT1

Attempting to utilize the sample in: File->New Project->Samples->Html5->Cordova Maps Sample
give me the infamous:

```
Project folder already exist and is not empty
```

Hence i tried executing Netbeans as root with:

```
gksu -u root "/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/bin/netbeans"
```

but to no avail.
Same result with changing the user dir in:

```
/usr/local/netbeans-8.0/etc/netbeans.conf
```

from: netbeans_default_userdir="${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT}/8.0"
to: netbeans_default_userdir="/usr/local/workplace_netbeans"

Uninstalling/Reinstalling the cordova plugin had the only effect to change the name category (in new project) from: Html5  to: ClientSide

### EDIT2

Netbeans log shows this null pointer exception that seems related to the Cordova wizard:
http://pastebin.com/2MFCd8Lr